# Android - Google Play force update all apps programmatically (admin)

Tags: android, google-play, admin, auto-update

Is there a way to force an update of a specific app from google play? Or toggle auto update? I have admin permission in my application.

Comment: yes there is a way to force update user https://jsoup.org/download

Comment: This open source GitHub project (MAHAndroidUpdater)is completely providing update functionality. Try it, Very simple. https://github.com/hummatli/MAHAndroidUpdater

Answer (score 0):

one Library available for checking APK version from google play store

use the following link [https://jsoup.org/download

and check version if it is lover than your current APK version then redirect user to play store.